# wildcard_constraints between two wildcards with OR

Tags: snakemake

I'd like to constraint a rule based on two wildcards to run if `(id == 'FOO || (id == 'BAR' && ver == '2'))`. However, I am not quite sure how to do it (or if it is possible). I tried the example below but it doesn't seem to work...

```
rule foo:
    input: "{id}{ver}.txt"
    output: "{id}{ver}.out"
    wildcard_constraints:
       id = "FOO"
    wildcard_constraints:
       id = "BAR",
       ver = "2"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure your current approach will work. Why not simply ask snakemake to make you files you need? e.g.:

```
rule all:
  input: expand('FOO{ver}.txt, ver=[somelist]), 'BAR2.txt'

rule foo:
  input: "{id}{ver}.txt"
  output: "{id}{ver}.out"
  shell: "some_command {input} > {output}
```

this should call rule foo for all foo{ver}.txt files you specify and for the bar2.txt file